# using Soil unresolved externals

Tags: c++, opengl-es, soil

i'm using Soil in my project,i add soil in my include directories and in my precompiled header i include "Soil.h".
and for the library in my precompied header i add this:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"SOIL")
```

but i got this errors:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__wglGetProcAddress@4 referenced in function _query_DXT_capability
```

what is wrong with it?
i'm using visual studio 2013,i add my additional include file in solution properties and additional library directories in it.

Comment: you should include header file like `#include "soil.h"`

Comment: yeah i do it but still got the same error!

Comment: is the library called just "SOIL", not "SOIL.lib" ? If so, try also linking OpenGL32.lib, which should contain wglGetProcAddress

Comment: search for this function `wglGetProcAddress@4` and by right click goto definition see it is going to defionition or not?

Comment: it's SOIL,
i tried everything but it didn't work! can anyone help me with it?

Comment: have you tried if linking OpenGL32.lib helps? That is where wglGetProcAddress is defined.

Comment: i'm using openGL ES2.0 is this make sence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`wglGetProcAddress`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation says explicitely that it resides in `Opengl32.lib`.